# Highlight words with RegEx on RichTextBox with SilverLight

Tags: regex, parsing, silverlight-4.0, richtextbox

Im trying to highlight words, letters or anything marked in a Regular Expression.
Im using RichTextBox in Silverlight (take care that Silverlight has NOT uses the same .NET Framework than others apps, for example it HAS NOT the TextRange)

Everytime the text has a \r\n or \n\r the pointers moves 4 position forward. But the really bad is when i do the highlight, the style text add 4 positions more. Even, i think he has more erratic behavior than racional. Please advice me something in this!

Thanks FailDev.

The text im using for try this is:

ffffffffffafffffffffff
fffffafffffffffff
fffffffffffffafffffffff

(4 lines, after the last f there is a carrier return \ line feed)

Also this one doesnt work with my code (has the erratic behavior, or not):

ffffffffffaaffffffafffff
fffffafffffffffff
fffffffffffffafffffffff

(4 lines, after the last f there is a carrier return \line feed)

The idea is highlight with blue, bold and underline the "a" character.

The last code that i tried is this:

```
MatchCollection CarrierReturns =  MainGeneral.Build_Regex(@"[\r\n|\n\r]", false);

            MatchCollection WordsFound =  MainGeneral.Build_Regex("[a]", false);
            foreach (Match x in WordsFound) {
                int StringCarrierCount = 0;

                if (CarrierReturns.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Match CR in CarrierReturns)
                    {
                        if (x.Index > CR.Index)
                        {
                            textBox1.Text += " CI:" + StringCarrierCount + "- ";
                            break;
                        }
                        StringCarrierCount++;
                    }
                }

                if (x.Index < CarrierReturns[0].Index) { StringCarrierCount = 0; }

                StringBegin = 2 + x.Index + (4 * StringColorCounter) + (4 *  StringCarrierCount);
                StringEnd = StringBegin + x.Length;
                textBox1.Text += StringBegin + "-" + StringEnd + " ";
                StringColorCounter++;

                StartPoint = MainData.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(StringBegin, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                EndPoint = MainData.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(StringEnd, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                MainData.Selection.Select(StartPoint, EndPoint);
                MainData.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue));
                MainData.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Run.TextDecorationsProperty, TextDecorations.Underline);
                MainData.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
            }
```

Thanks in advance, please ask me before rate bad! :)

Comment: We need input/regex/output. All the other "noise" you posted is of no use to us.

Comment: I really solve this problem applying xaml on the feed (that came as plain text) and putting all in a paragraph block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line separator may be any of `\r\n` (carriage-return + linefeed), `\n` (linefeed alone), or `\r` (carriage-return alone).  The correct way to match one would be with `\r\n|[\r\n]`.

Your regex - `[\r\n|\n\r]` - matches exactly one character; any of `\r`, `\n`, or `|`.  That means, whenever the line separator is `\r\n`, your code acts like there are **two** line separators, not one.

There may be other errors in your code as well, but I don't really understand what it's trying to do.  I'm sure the regex is incorrect.

Comment: No, first of all because im in windows, CRLF in richtextbox is always two chars: CR and LF.
Second the first example works fine, the second doesnt. The RegEx is OK, as I said, the problem is that the pointer moves when i apply font styles, with text plain there is NO problem at all parsing with regex. Thanks anyway

Comment: If that's a .NET regex, everything between the square brackets forms a set of characters, to be matched individually.  Each time it's applied, it matches one character: `\r`, `\n`, or `|`.  Is that really what you intended?  And why are you trying to match `\n\r` anyway, if you know the line separators are always `\r\n`?

Comment: Because i accept copy paste from i-dont-know-where :( Also if i try with \r or \n special chrs not be added. That i wanted is catch \r\n OR \n\r :S Thanks for the tip