# RichTextBox search'n'replace results are staggered

Tags: regex, silverlight, richtextbox

I am currently trying to generate colored results after a search containing keywords. My code displays a richtextbox containing a text that was succesfully hit by the search engine.

Now I want to highlight the keywords in the text, by making them bold and colored in red. I have my list of words in a nice string table, which I browse this way (rtb is my RichTextBox, plainText is the only Run from rtb, containing the entire text of it) :

```
rtb.SelectAll();
string allText = rtb.Selection.Text;
string expression = "";
foreach (string word in words)
{
    expression = Regex.Escape(word);
    Regex regExp = new Regex(expression);
    foreach (Match match in regExp.Matches(allText))
    {
        TextPointer start = plainText.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Index, LogicalDirection.Forward);
        TextPointer end = plainText.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Index + match.Length, LogicalDirection.Forward);
        rtb.Selection.Select(start, end);
        rtb.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Run.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
        rtb.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Run.ForegroundProperty, "red");
    }
}
```

Now I thought this would do the trick. But somehow, only the first word gets highlighted correctly. Then, the second occurence of the highlights starts two early, with the correct amount of letters getting highlighted, but a few characters before the actual word. Then for the third occurence it's further more characters earlier, etc.

Have you got any idea what is causing this behavior?

EDIT (01/07/2013): Still not figuring out why these results are staggered... So far I noticed that if I created a variable set to zero right before the second foreach statement, added it up to each textpointer's positions and incremented it by 4 (no idea why) at the end of each loop, the results are colored adequately. Nevertheless, if I search for two keywords or more (doesn't matter if they're the same size), each occurence of the first keyword get colored correctly, but only the first occurences of the other keywords are well-colored. (the others are staggered again) Here's the edited code:

```
rtb.SelectAll();
string allText = rtb.Selection.Text;
string expression = "";
foreach (string word in words)
{
    expression = Regex.Escape(word);
    Regex regExp = new Regex(expression);
    int i = 0;
    foreach (Match match in regExp.Matches(allText))
    {
        TextPointer start = plainText.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Index + i, LogicalDirection.Forward);
        TextPointer end = plainText.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Index + match.Length + i, LogicalDirection.Forward);
        rtb.Selection.Select(start, end);
        rtb.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Run.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
        rtb.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Run.ForegroundProperty, "red");
        i += 4; // number found out from trials
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, RichTextBox.Select() does not exist in Silverlight :( and if I do that using RichTextBox.Selection.Select(), I get invalid arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright! So I learned by reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152546/highlight-words-with-regex-on-richtextbox-with-silverlight) that everytime I modify the style, it adds 4 characters to the text, which is what was messing up my setting.

In order to fix this, since I possibly have multiple keywords and that they do not appear one after the other in the text in the order that they were typed in the search box, I had to first browse my text to locate each occurence for each keyword **without modifying the text**. For each occurence, I store in a custom list the **start position**, **end position** and **desired color** of the occurence.

When this selection is done, I order my occurence list by the **start** attribute of each member in it. I can now be assured that each occurence I browse in my **foreach** loop is the next one in the text, with no regard to its content or length. And I know in which color I want to make it appear, so I can distinguish different keywords.

Then, finally, I can browse each member of my ordered list and modify the style of my text, knowing that the next word will appear later in the text, so I must add 4 characters to my index at the end of each loop.